# Igloo Software: Confirm successful transfer to local machine

Tags: windows, git, version-control

I have a lot of files stored in Igloo that I am copying over to my local machine, and must confirm that everything was indeed copied over successfully without missing any files/folders. There are lots of directories and sub-directories so manually checking that takes a long time. Does anybody know how to use Git/winmerge, Igloo's version control, or another 'diff checker' solution to make sure everything was copied over successfully from Igloo to my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you use git to version control your lgloo software, it will make things easier.

**Remote git repo:** setup your own remote repo, or sign up for github/bitbucket etc and hosted your remote repo there.

**Local git repo:** make changes for lgloo and sync with remote repo.

**First time to sync with local repo to remote:**

```
# In an empty local path
git init
# copy lgloo software in the path
git add .
git commit -m 'init commit'
git remote add origin <URL for remote repo>
git push -u origin master
```

After that, when you want to **copy the whole lgloo software into your local machine and check if it copied successfully**. You just need to execute the commands in the same local path:

```
git pull origin master
git log master..origin/master
```

If there is no output after `git log master..origin/master`, that means you copied the latest lgloo software successfully.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution, but what do I do after copying the Igloo software path? How/when do I tell git about that path?

Comment: The local git repo just locate in the path, so you can do what you want to change for your lgloo software. Then you can use `git add .`, `git commit` and `git push`. And it's no need to tell git the path. More details about git, you can refer git book https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2.

Comment: Did you execute git commands successfully? If the answer help you solve the problem, you can mark it as answer. And it will help others who have similar question.